# Icone do App não aparece no Smartphone Android

Tags: unity3d, app

Estou aprendendo Android e executei no Unity o BUILD para Android e o arquivo `.apk` foi instalado aos Apps do smartphone.

No instante em que a instalação foi concluída com sucesso, nota-se duas situações:

1- O botão "CONCLUIDO" na tela do smartphone está ativo, e o botão "ABRIR" está inativo.

2- O ícone do App não foi criado na tela do Smartphone.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que nas 2 mensagens de erro no console do Unity esteja a solução, porém não sei localizar e nem o quê fazer para corrigir o problema.

Comment: Da uma olhada no ícone que você colocou, tente outro. Já aconteceu comigo, troquei o ícone e funcionou, pode ser isso

Comment: você está usando o Android Studio? e tem como postar o xml aqui?